# How does fumed silica attain a panel shape when used in vacuum insulated panels?

Tags: vacuum, vacuum-pumps

VIPs are shaped like fairly-flat boxes - cuboids - thick rectangles, for example 20 mm x 400 x 600 mm. If manufacturing started with a sheet of styrofoam - a thick rectangle - I would not be surprised that the VIP has the same shape. In videos I've seen of vacuum-packing loose powders, the result is not panel-shaped. (Fumed silica is not technically a powder, but for the purposes of this question I think I can say it's powder-like.)

Do the vacuum chambers include flat plates that physically shape the powder inside their envelope before/during the vacuuming? I've seen many types of vacuum chambers for sale, but none include plates for shaping the contents. How does fumed silica attain a panel shape when used in vacuum insulated panels?

Comment: Did the examples you saw overfill and skim off a layer of powder against the rim to make the top flat? 3D printers that operate on powdered materials do this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yiUUZxp7bLQ&t=60s

Comment: Can you link to the video in question?

Comment: By the way, asking for a vacuum chamber that includes a mold is probably asking too much: molds are very specific and are custom made for the part. What you should be looking for instead are accommodations to accept a mold.

Comment: Video of powder being vacuum sealed in a vacuum chamber, not resulting in a panel-shaped thick-rectangle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2eES_QB1bOM?t=90.  (The same process is repeated three times.  Just see the first - they're all the same.)